# mongodb nested array get count of array element by grouping

Tags: node.js, mongodb

my mongodb document structure which contains hierarchy VALUES => 1 (HOUR) => 0 (MIUNTES) => STATUS VALUES ARRAY (WITH FIX VALUES ie 1,2,3,4 only)

```
{
"_id" : 100,
"values" : {
    "1" : {
        "0" : { "status_values" : [ 0, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 4 ] },
        "1" : { "status_values" : [ 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 3, 4 ] },
        "2" : { "status_values" : [ 2, 2, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 4 ] }
    },
    "2" : {
        "0" : { "status_values" : [ 0, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 4 ] },
        "1" : { "status_values" : [ 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 3, 4 },
        "2" : { "status_values" : [ 2, 2, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 4 ] }
    }
},
"timestamp" : ISODate("2016-01-15T00:00:00.000Z")
}
```

expected output 
count of status_values goup by MINUTES, HOUR